# neo4j Exception when stopping org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource

Tags: java, neo4j

When shutting down the noo4j DB I receive this error:

```
[org.neo4j]: Exception when stopping org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@45673f68 java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=16 lim=1048576 cap=1048576], 1586985
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=16 lim=1048576 cap=1048576], 1586985
    at org.neo4j.test.impl.EphemeralFileSystemAbstraction$DynamicByteBuffer.put(EphemeralFileSystemAbstraction.java:966)
    at org.neo4j.test.impl.EphemeralFileSystemAbstraction$EphemeralFileData.write(EphemeralFileSystemAbstraction.java:680)
    at org.neo4j.test.impl.EphemeralFileSystemAbstraction$EphemeralFileChannel.write(EphemeralFileSystemAbstraction.java:488)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel.write(StoreFileChannel.java:160)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore$1.perform(CommonAbstractStore.java:579)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.FileUtils.windowsSafeIOOperation(FileUtils.java:367)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.close(CommonAbstractStore.java:572)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.NeoStore.closeStorage(NeoStore.java:289)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.close(CommonAbstractStore.java:552)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.stop(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:507)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:527)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.stop(XaDataSourceManager.java:185)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:527)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:185)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.shutdown(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:822)
    at org.neo4j.test.ImpermanentGraphDatabase.shutdown(ImpermanentGraphDatabase.java:170)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.DelegatingGraphDatabase.shutdown(DelegatingGraphDatabase.java:270)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeCustomDestroyMethod(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:565)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:870)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:510)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:884)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:804)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:244)
    at org.neo4j.test.impl.EphemeralFileSystemAbstraction$DynamicByteBuffer.put(EphemeralFileSystemAbstraction.java:962)
    ... 31 more
2014-11-20 18:31:03.775+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Exception when stopping org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@4fd91628 Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@45673f68' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@45673f68' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:532)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.stop(XaDataSourceManager.java:185)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:527)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:185)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.shutdown(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:822)
```

I assume it is caused by a timeout, as it only appears when instantiating a large number of nodes (> 100K). However, I do not find a way to set up any timeout using the setConfig/GraphDatabaseSettings APIs (unfortunately we cannot use a property file):

```
 public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
    .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder("db/my.db")
    .setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.nodestore_mapped_memory_size, "10M" )
    .newGraphDatabase();
```

Do you know what is the root cause of the issue and how to circumvent it?

Thanks

F.

Comment: The stacktrace indicates you're using `ImpermanentGraphDatabaseService` which is only intended for usage in your unit tests. Please double check that you don't use IGDS for large stuff.

Comment: Stefan, thanks for the prompt response. I'm using an embedded DB as in my example above: return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("db/my.db"); and the 100K entries is for our unit tests.  I'll double check. Thanks F.

Comment: Can you share your spring (java) config for the test? It clearly shows that it uses the `ImpermanentGraphDatabaseService`. You probably have a test config overriding stuff. For creating databases you can also use `GraphDatbaseServiceFactoryBean`

Comment: Michael, thanks for replying. I do not have a config per se. Our config is done directly in java code and not a lot more than what I reported above.